# How do I shutdown and throw an exception when an Apache Camel FTP Route has a connection error?

Tags: apache-camel

I have the following Apache Camel FTP file download Route:

```
        from(downloadUri)
            .routeId(routeId)
            .aggregate(new CustomListAggregationStrategy())
            .constant(true)
            .completionFromBatchConsumer()
            .to("direct:" + routeDestinationId);
```

I add this Route to a context and then request data with a ConsumerTemplate:

```
List<ResultType> result = consumerTemplate.receiveBody(CAMEL_DIRECT_OBJECT_PREFIX
                        + routeId, List.class);
```

When a connection error occurs (e.g. unknown host, host not reachable), I want to shutdown the Route and throw an exception after the "receiveBody" line where I try to read the downloaded files.

How can I do this?

I tried an onException-handler for the Route where I added a process block to it and called exchange.getContext().stop(); in that processing block. But the application just keeps running.

Comment: I think what you need is a `Circuit Breaker` allowing you to pause message consumption when an error threshold is reached. See good article here : https://dzone.com/articles/circuit-breaker-pattern-apache

Comment: Your use case is really unclear. Please describe your use case in more details.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping a route during routing an existing message is a bit tricky. The reason for that is Camel will Graceful Shutdown the route you are stopping. And if you do that while a message is being routed the Graceful Shutdown will try to wait until that message has been processed.

You can find more info here : https://camel.apache.org/manual/faq/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html